# the lower bound time of building a binary search tree by inserting n random elements sequently

Tags: algorithm

The time can be proportional to sum of depth of all nodes.

T(n): the minimal depth sum of all possible BSTs with n elements.

So, T(n) = n-1 + min(T(i)+T(n-1-i)), i from 0 to n-1.

I think that the lower bound should be Θ(n lg n), but I can not prove it.

Answer (score 2):

The lower bound time complexity for building a binary tree from an input stream would be achieved when we can add nodes as high up in the tree as possible (having the least *depth*). This way the tree remains optimally balanced throughout the process. For instance, we could have this input stream:

```
4 2 6 1 3 5 7
```

...which really provides the values for the future tree in level order (breadth-first order).

The time complexity for the individual insertions is linear to the number of nodes to traverse, i.e. the height of the tree at the moment of insertion. This height is O(log), where  is the size of the tree at the moment of insertion.

In general, we have this equality for the combined work of all insertions:

T = Θ( ∑<sub><sub>=1..</sub></sub> log )

Which by the [logarithm product rule](https://www.rapidtables.com/math/algebra/Logarithm.html#product-rule) is:

T = Θ(log(!))

Which by [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) means that:

T = Θ(log)

Comment: Ok，what you say is that the tree should always be a complete binary tree on every iteration?

Comment: Ok，what you say is that the tree should always be a complete binary tree on every iteration?

Comment: No, not exactly. It should be a tree which has its leaves in at most two levels. A complete tree fulfils that condition, but the leaves in the bottom level could be spread around, instead of being packed at the left side (which is what happens in a complete tree).

Comment: I can prove it by mathematical induction.

Comment: I can prove it by mathematical induction.